# How to override a windows hook?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is there a way to override the hook for <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

I want to execute my program instead of the default behavior.

I'm on windows enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)

In your case you could use a script like this:

```
#Tab::Run, notepad.exe
```

You can find more details here: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm